# Deploying laravel MySQL database on remote server

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, deployment

How can I deploy MySQL database on a remote server?

I have an idea but I don't know it's true or not :
I think,I should create database on the server and then run migration command and then create dotenv file.is it true?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1):

Just create the database, then properly configure `.env` file and run: `php artisan migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I deploy MySQL database on a remote server?

You simply create a user in your remote host. Allow the ip from where your laravel app can access the database. it can add an extra layer of security.

simply change the .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=yourconnect
DB_HOST=your host ip
DB_DATABASE=db name
DB_USERNAME=db username
DB_PASSWORD=db password
```